# Ubuntu 12.10 freezes after boot

Tags: 12.10, boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 but I am having a hard time. First, tried from WUBI (Windows installer), all went fine, dual-boot worked, but as soon as Ubuntu boots, it freezes - even before the Login screen is fully loaded. I have tried installing via USB with LinuxLive USB Creator, but had the same exact issue.

I use an Intel Core 2 Duo 2, 8 GHz, 4 GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 9400GT 512 MB.

Comment: Can you press ctrl+alt+F1/F2 and get to command prompt. If yes then please let us know, we can help you to debug problem or upgrade drivers, if necessary

Comment: I can only press when Ubuntu is booting ( Ubuntu logo and the dots appear ). I tried the following comands alredy: sudo apt-add-repository ppa: ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates , sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install nvidia current nvidia-settings . Nothing happend after i gave those comands and it still freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; I think it's somewhere along the lines of the Nvidia and the 64 bit version of Ubuntu it reads the display at a higher resolution than what it's actually operating at. What I ended up doing was running the 64 bit version of 10.04 and that had a distorted display that I was able to fix by changing the resolution and then installed the nvidia drivers; I'm still running 10.04, but after you have it you do have the option to upgrade using the update manager.

Comment: I am trying to install 32bit version.

Comment: Good luck; I wish I could say with 100% certainty what the problem was, but unfortunately I would just be lying to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Download [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and then write Ubuntu to your USB drive with it. After this, boot your computer from USB and it must work. Also try to install Nvidia drivers:

- Open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or if live session works, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
- Then add the PPA and install the required packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
  ```

But this will not work on liveDVD or liveCD. It works on installed system and LiveUSB only.

Comment: Did this, did not worked. Freezed at same spot, when i tried to open the terminal it and started typing said "Kernel Panic", i then tested the memory and it said "Cannot access RAM Memory with old kernel". What should i do?